# Create folder inner folder with Google Drive SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a folder using the Google Drive SDK for iOS.
I Use as below code, Main drive in create  folder inner create.

```
GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
folder.title = @"Testing";
folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
NSString *parentId = @"Testing";

folder.parents = @[parentId];

// ... execute query


GTLQueryDrive *query1 = [GTLQueryDrive     queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
[self.driveService executeQuery:query1 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                              NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Created folder %@",updatedFile.identifier);

         GTLDriveParentReference *parentReference = [GTLDriveParentReference object];

         parentReference.identifier = updatedFile.identifier;
         GTLDriveFile *subFolder = [GTLDriveFile object];
         subFolder.title = @"Testing12352";
         subFolder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
         NSString *parentId = updatedFile.identifier;
         subFolder.parents =  @[parentReference];

        // ... execute query

        GTLQueryDrive *query1 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
        [self.driveService executeQuery:query1 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                   GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                                   NSError *error)
         {
             if (error == nil)
             {
                  NSLog(@"Created folder %@",updatedFile.parents);
             }
         }];
```

Work Perfect. 
Google drive Folder inner folder create..

Comment: You want to create `Testing` folder in root and `Testing12352` inside `Testing` folder right?

Comment: @NiravD Yes....

Comment: @NiravD : you have solution?

Comment: The answer I'have previously posted is works for me, i don't know why it is not works for you, that is the reason i have deleted that answer.

Comment: Are you able to create Testing folder in the main root of Google Doc with my answer?

Comment: Yes Testing folder created via your code but not inner Testing12353.

Comment: I have undelete the answer, check properly in the response of testing folder i have set `subFolder.parents` as `updatedFile.identifier;` have you set like that too?

Comment: I did copy code as you mention but not create folder inner folder. its create on root.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create `Testing` folder in `root` and `Testing12352` inside `Testing` folder then for `Testing` you need to set `parents` to `[@"root"]` and for `Testing12352` you need to set Testing's `identifier` as `parents`.

```
GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
folder.title = @"Testing";
folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
NSString *parentId = @"root";

folder.parents = @[parentId];

// ... execute query



GTLQueryDrive *query1 = [GTLQueryDrive     queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
[self.driveService executeQuery:query1 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
    GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
    NSError *error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Created folder %@",updatedFile.identifier);



            GTLDriveFile *subFolder = [GTLDriveFile object];
            subFolder.title = @"Testing12352";
            subFolder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
            NSString *parentId = updatedFile.identifier;
            subFolder.parents = @[parentId];

            // ... execute query

            GTLQueryDrive *query1 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:subFolder uploadParameters:nil];
            [self.driveService executeQuery:query1 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
            GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
            NSError *error)
            {
                if (error == nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Created folder %@",updatedFile.parents);
                }
            }];
```

**Note :** Don't forgot to set `scope` to `kGTLAuthScopeDrive`

Comment: I try to set parentId = @"root" but its not create folder inner folder..

Comment: You have demo so please send me on vishalvaghasiya.90@gmail.com

Comment: i Got Solution..
    GTLDriveParentReference *parentReference =     [GTLDriveParentReference object];
      parentReference.identifier = updatedFile.identifier;

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya And what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
    func createFolder(
    subFolderName: String,
    service: GTLRDriveService,
    completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    
    let folder = GTLRDrive_File()
    let parentId = "root"
    folder.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    folder.name = "MainFolder"
    folder.parents = [parentId]
    
    // Google Drive folders are files with a special MIME-type.
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: folder, uploadParameters: nil)
    
    service.executeQuery(query) { (_, file, error) in
        
        if error == nil {
            
            let folder = file as! GTLRDrive_File
            print("MainFolder Id \(folder.identifier!)")
            
            let subFolder = GTLRDrive_File()
            subFolder.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
            subFolder.name = subFolderName
            subFolder.parents = [folder.identifier!]
            
            let query2 = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: subFolder, uploadParameters: nil)
            
            service.executeQuery(query2) { (_, file2, error2) in
                
                if error2 == nil {
                    
                    let folder2 = file2 as! GTLRDrive_File
                    
                    print("subfolder Id \(folder2.identifier!)")
                    completion(folder2.identifier!)
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```